# Use of AsyncWaitHandle in BeginXXX and EndXXX methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dns

I would like to call an asynchronous operation that returns an `IAsyncResult` object, in particular the `GetHostEntry` method of the `System.Net.Dns` class.

I had understood that I should call the `WaitOne` method of the `AsyncWaitHandle` property of `IAsyncResult` to wait with a certain timeout for the operation to complete, but evidently I'm wrong, as this piece of code does not work:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

static class Program {

    class GetHostEntryState {
        public IPHostEntry Value {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string hostName = "somehost";
        int timeout = 1000;

        var state = new GetHostEntryState();
        var asyncResult = Dns.BeginGetHostEntry(hostName, ar => {
            ((GetHostEntryState)ar.AsyncState).Value = Dns.EndGetHostEntry(ar);
        }, state);
        if (asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout) && asyncResult.IsCompleted) {
            if (state.Value == null) {
                // we always hit this condition
                Console.WriteLine("state.Value == null");
                return;
            }
            foreach (var address in state.Value.AddressList) {
                Console.WriteLine(address);
            }
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("timed out");
        }
    }
}
```

The [example in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143990.aspx) uses a `ManualResetEvent` object to do the synchronization. Is that necessary? If so, what's the use of the `AsyncWaitHandle` property here?

Comment: You can tell it is necessary by what you saw.  You've got a threading race, the AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne() usually completes before the callback is made.  You got into this pickle by calling an asynchronous method but waiting for it synchronously.  Probably because you wanted the timeout.  The next thing you have to fret about is how you clean up when you've got a timeout.

Comment: @HansPassant: but then what's the AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne() purpose? I  still don't get it...

Comment: It's purpose is to tell you when you can call the EndXxx() method without it blocking.  Which would work by having no callback and calling EndGetHostEntry() after the WaitOne() call.  But you can't afford that because of the timeout.  Not calling it causes a resource leak.

Comment: @HansPassant: thanks, I think I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

Since what I wanted was a GetHostEntry with a timeout, I came up with this solution, which, if I understood correctly, should avoid leaking resources as eventually the EndGetHostEntry operation will be called anyway.

I'm sharing it here in case it will be useful for someone else :)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

public sealed class HostEntryTimeout {

    public IPHostEntry HostEntry {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    string _hostName;
    int _timeoutInMilliseconds;
    ManualResetEvent _getHostEntryFinished;

    public HostEntryTimeout(string alias, int timeoutInMilliseconds) {
        _hostName = alias;
        _timeoutInMilliseconds = timeoutInMilliseconds;
        _getHostEntryFinished = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the IPHostEntry.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if successful, false otherwise.</returns>
    public bool GetHostEntry() {
        _getHostEntryFinished.Reset();
        Dns.BeginGetHostEntry(_hostName, GetHostEntryCallback, null);
        if (!_getHostEntryFinished.WaitOne(_timeoutInMilliseconds)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (HostEntry == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void GetHostEntryCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult) {
        try {
            HostEntry = Dns.EndGetHostEntry(asyncResult);
        } catch (SocketException) {
        }
        _getHostEntryFinished.Set();
    }
}
```

Then it can be used like this:

```
var hostEntryTimeout = new HostEntryTimeout("somehost", 1000);
if (hostEntryTimeout.GetHostEntry()) {
    // success, do something with the hostEntryTimeout.HostEntry object
}
```